# Possibility to sync content of logical folder with physical folder in netbeans c++?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I was wondering if it was possible somehow to only work in the "Files" tab of netbeans when working on c++ projects. Currently, netbeans won't update the makefiles if I add source files only there (without also adding them in the "Projects" tab).

Maybe this is just a problem of me not understanding the concept of logical folders correctly.
Currently I am a bit confused, since I cannot imagine that the netbeans developers expect me to have no order in my physical source folder at all. What about sharing my project with developers outside of netbeans? The physical location of my source actually DOES matter to me. And manually moving everything to the correct directory or adding it to a logical directory each time I create a new file seems like being unnecessarily complicated, too.

This is why I formulated my question like this, looking for a way to shadow the content of a physical directory to a logical folder or vice versa. I hope you can clear things up for me.

My netbeans version is 8.0 and I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- Create a proper custom C(++) project using the "new project" wizard or
- Simply drag & drop your folder to Netbeans, which will make it browsable in the "files" tab. I do this occasionally for HTML / JS work, were no project type Netbeans offers is a good match, and I want to use it as a simple editor.

Comment: I don't think this really answers my question. If I understand you correctly, you suggest 
a) I use the normal c++ project setup wizard, which I did and
b) that I use netbeans merely as an editor, which defeats the purpose of an IDE somehow, no?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. But then I don't understand what the problem is, because for me the project view reflects the actual directory layout (having a cmake-based C++ project, with sources / headers scattered in several subfolders).

Comment: Ok, there we seem to have a difference. Maybe it's the netbeans version? https://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html#SwitchingViews states, that the project tab is the logical part whereas the files tab is the physical. I find tedious to sync both sides manually. I could ignore the logical view, but then netbeans won't update my build files, which is what I'm after. Or I only work in the logical, view, but don't have a physical ordering on my files. Still, thanks a lot for taking time to answer!

Comment: I can only suggest you try to create a completely new project using the wizard, and the try to find out where it differs from your misbehaving project. Good luck with that. :-)